# Error when pushing to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I have created a new sfdx project and pulled source from a managed package. When I try to push the source to a scratch org I get

```
ERROR:  Cannot read property 'getAggregateFullNameFromFilePath' of null.
```

I have never seen this error before and was not able to find anything while Googling around. Has anyone ever seen this error or know what that property is?

Comment: I've seen this on *existing* projects where SFDX somehow gets into an inconsistent state, the remedy being to delete all the project cache files and sometimes reinstall SFDX. I'm not sure that applies with a *new* project.

Comment: Okay great I will give that a try

Comment: I have also seen this only recently - for me deleting .sfdx worked.

Comment: Another option: check you don’t have a lightning component with a <style> attribute in it being in API 42. This tag has been removed in Spring.

Comment: FWIW, I had this error and it turned out to be a syntax error in the JS controller fo a lightning component. However, the only way I realised this was to recreate each component manually in a scratch org, copy the code across, and then save it (eventually one failed, and fixing it solved the problem.) I only had around 10 lightning components though so this was annoying, but feasible. If you have hundreds then not so much...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it throw any errors if you try and convert it to MDAPI format?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error recently.

I found a corresponding failed deployment in the scratch org by a quick find for "Deployment status" in setup.

Please look there for details on failure.

Comment: This does not provide an asnwer to the question, please make sure you ahve enough rep in order to be able to leave comments son posts. To do so, participate in the forum and please review [answer] . thanks!

Comment: The answer does provide valuable info. If you get `getAggregateFullNameFromFilePath` on the command line, go to your Scratch Org and check the Deployment Status.

Comment: Thanks Christian Szandor Knapp.  Checking the deployment status provides valuable info on the failure - like which component or class failed to deploy.  I was able to address the root cause of all my failures by following this approach.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same error, and the reason was a syntax error in one of the lightning components. We are working with VS code and we had this error by pushing to scratch org. The reason was a simple syntax error: we wrote 
`<aura:attribute name"theName" type="something">` 
instead of 
`<aura:attribute name="theName" type="something">`