# DX: force:soure:push Cannot read property 'getAggregateFullNameFromFilePath' of null

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm following this [Trailhead tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_build_app) and I'm at "Creating Additional Lightning Components" step 9 where I need to push my lightning components to my scratch org, but when I try to do so I get the following error

> ERROR:  Cannot read property 'getAggregateFullNameFromFilePath' of null

I've tried from Visual Studios Code terminal window and from Command Prompt.  I'm running Windows 7.

I was able to push/pull earlier, not sure how to debug this.

Comment: See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208350/error-when-pushing-to-scratch-org) from yesterday for some suggestions.

Comment: @DavidReed  Thanks, turns out it was a JavaScript issue.  Copying the file from the trailhead worked.  This can be marked as duplicate.